# Asp.net url routing in application having more than one page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using URL routing to make links to users profiles in asp.net, its work but the rest pages of the application not work , did i have to define a route for all pages or i miss something in somewhere.

I don't work with asp.net mvc but with asp.net web forms.

For profile page i want the routing but there is pages i just wont to use a asp x link to it
 but all the pages now have the same URL defined in the routes in the global file.
 I write this problem before two days always i have a problem.

Comment: Can you post your code?  It's hard to tell without it.

Comment: it is not about code i think i have problem in the concept i have a community site include home profile photos ... there is no problem with pages that i used session for get info to built it but wih profiles i need routing to make route for each user based on id i made it but now home  or other pages didn't work they all use the route i made it in the global after i go to a profile by it

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your routes with [ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger Visualizer](http://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/)
or take a look at the [blog of Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: OK to be more specific i have 5 pages .asp x i want to make a route in URL routing for one of them i made it but the whole project affected by that route did i need to make a route for each page OK i made it but it affected by the ones the user used

Comment: for example the route profile/user id it works but after i used it another page like home became with URL like profile/home and its not in mvc thanks in advanced please help iam running out of time

Comment: thx every body i found it each page must have a route some with static others dynamic and using the getrouteurl function to build url either with {para} or {null} for static